# Change beanstalkd default TTR

Tags: service, beanstalkd, beanstalkc

I run `beanstalkd` as a service using the standard `/etc/default/beanstalkd`.

Sometimes my code throws a `NOT_FOUND` error when I try to delete a job, because it got released due to exceeding the TTR. I would like to increase the TTR for *all* jobs that get inserted into the tubes.

**Is there a way to set a default TTR for `beanstalkd` jobs?** My guess is that I can change this somewhere in /etc/default/beanstalkd, but I couldn't find this in the `beanstalkd` docs.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There isn't a way to set a global default, in /etc/default/beanstalkd or elsewhere, but it is easy enough to setup a wrapper function/class that all jobs are funnelled through to then be inserted to the queue, that would set a TTR (the parameter to the PUT command), if it was not specifically set.

In beanstalkc, that would override/replace the `put` function.

```
def put(self, body, priority=DEFAULT_PRIORITY, delay=0, ttr=DEFAULT_TTR):
```

Answer (score 7):

It sounds to me that you didn't implemented the protocol properly. You need to handle `DEADLINE_SOON`, and do `TOUCH`.

**What does DEADLINE_SOON mean?**

`DEADLINE_SOON` is a response to a reserve command indicating that you have a job reserved whose deadline is real soon (current safety margin is approximately 1 second).

If you are frequently receiving `DEADLINE_SOON` errors on reserve, you should probably consider increasing the TTR on your jobs as it generally indicates you aren’t completing them in time. It may also be that you are failing to delete tasks when you have completed them.

See the [mailing list discussion](http://groups.google.com/group/beanstalk-talk/browse_thread/thread/232d0cac5bebe30f) for more information.

**How does TTR work?**

`TTR` only applies to a job at the moment it becomes reserved. At that event, a timer (called “time-left” in the job stats) starts counting down from the job’s `TTR`.

- If the timer reaches zero, the job gets put back in the ready queue.
- If the job is buried, deleted, or released before the timer runs out, the timer ceases to exist.
- If the job is touch"ed before the timer reaches zero, the timer starts over counting down from TTR.

**The "touch" command**

Allows a worker to request more time to work on a job.
This is useful for jobs that potentially take a long time, but you still want
the benefits of a `TTR` pulling a job away from an unresponsive worker.  A worker
may periodically tell the server that it's still alive and processing a job
(e.g. it may do this on `DEADLINE_SOON`). The command postpones the auto
release of a reserved job until `TTR` seconds from when the command is issued.